# Column-count Sort Left to Right for a <ul> List

Tags: html, list, css

I have the following html and css structure. The problem I am having is that the `<li>` items are sorted Top to Bottom, instead of Left to Right.

I have tried to follow the solutions on other similar posts but it didn't work out for my specific structure. Any ideas please?

```css
#mylist {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 0 2% 5%;
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  width: 100%;
}

#mylist li {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #eaeaea;
  padding: 3px 0;
  margin: 5% 0.5% 0% 0.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>
    <a id="floimg" href="/">
      <img width="180" height="180" src="img.jpg" class="attachment-mini-me size-mini-me wp-post-image"><span class="flotnm">My Label</span>
      <div class="emic">
        <div class="emif">
          <i id="flocut" class="x-icon x-icon-bookmark-o" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="feme">Designer</span>
        </div>
        <div class="emis">
          <span class="flag"></span><span class="feme">French</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    ...same structure
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you want the list items in order left to right...don't use `column-count`. Use another layout method.

Comment: ok, I guess I will go with the float method for this example.

Answer (score 0):

With a width of 80% no two `li` elements can ever be in one line....

Comment: Those styles don't appear to be applied anyway.

Comment: i think we are talking about different things here.. My issue is that the items are sorted top to bottom - and I want them left to right. I think we can ignore the width part here as my items are displayed correctly, it's just the order which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Johannes. Further to this,

```
  min-width: 20%;
  max-width: 80%;
```

If you want them to fit in the same line if their widths will vary, then why not make the min-width a lower number? At most 50% if you want its neighbor to fit next to it.

Set the height to the same `min-height` as well if you want each `li` block to display well next to each other. For example, your code is here but I changed the min/max widths and simplified it. You can see the problem of how this doesn't present well: https://jsfiddle.net/yu2w14hp/2/ (the second `li` sort of goes under the image. You can fix this by fixing setting a minimum height/width or generally understanding how you want to display your `li` block).